# Node.js scalable/performance capabilities with large number of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am in the middle of creating a node.js project however I am concerned as to the performance of the website once it is up and running.

I am expecting it to have a surge of maybe 2000 users for 4-5 hours over a period of one night per week.

The issue is that each user could be receiving a very small message once every second. i.e a timer adjustment or a price change.
2000*60 = 120000 messages in total per minute.

Would this be possible it would be extremely important that there was minimum lag, less than 1 second if possible?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly scale the users with socket.io but the question is how you want to do that. It is unclear whether you have considered the `cluster` module as that will significantly take the load of the single node process for that amount of users and reduce the latency time. Of course when you do this you need to stop using the in-memory store that socket.io uses by default and use something like redis instead so that you don't end up with duplicate authentication handshakes. Socket.io even has a [document](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) to explain how to do this.

What you really need to do is test the performance of your application by creating 2000 clients and simulating 2000 users. The socket.io [client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client) can let you set this up in a node application (and then perhaps sign up for the free tier of an EC2 machine to run them all).

It's worth noting that I haven't actually seen v1.0 benchmarks and really the socket.io developers should have a page on it dedicated to benchmarks as this is always a common question with developers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, gives me some information to research.

I found this article Deif, perhaps it would also interest you. 
http://www.slideshare.net/FabianFrankDe/nodejs-performance-case-study